# Django, PostgreSQL - How to represent BitString fields in models

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models, bitstring

I use Django (1.6) with a PostgreSQL (9.3.2) backend for my web application. In my planned DB schema, I will have a bit string 128 bits long representing events that happen over a period of 4 months. The idea is that I can find intersections between various events by simply and'ing the fields together, among other things. My question is on how to implement this.

Some findings I have come across so far:

- PostgreSQL has a BitString type, so I'd ideally like to map the field to this type in the DB. Any other schemes would be also welcome.
- I can't use BigIntegerField (and hence [BitField extension](https://github.com/disqus/django-bitfield) by Disqus) since it allows only 64 bits.
- In python, I'd expect the data type to be either long (I use Python 2.7) or something like the BitArray class from [bitstring](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module.
- I came across [django-postgres](https://github.com/zacharyvoase/django-postgres) on github that would have served my purpose, but it's inactive at the moment. Perhaps there are other efforts I am unaware of?

What are my options here please? How to represent a BitString field in a Django model?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can implement and'ing operate in client or PostgreSQL server(use  bitwise &).  if use PostgreSQL server i recommend use bit string. if use client operator , use text also ok.

Comment: The and operation is itself not a problem. My question really is, can I avoid writing a custom Django model field for this purpose? Is there an existing solution I can use? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution?

Comment: @SeNorm Unfortunately, I never did. The problem sort of went away after we decided to do away with the feature to make room for more urgent ones.